# How can I retrieve rows using a key in a jsonb array?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, jsonb

datatype = _jsonb
column name = gates

Gates column value example:

`{"{\"ip_address\": \"192.168.1.10\", \"serial_number\": \"123\", \"gate_description\": \"Fourth gate\"}"}`

Postgresql version 15.2

I am getting below error

> SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function jsonb_path_query_array(jsonb[],
> unknown) does not exist   Hint: No function matches the given name and
> argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.   Position:
> 8

Error position: line: 12 pos: 7

I am using this query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array("gates", '$[*] ? (@.serial_number == "123")') as gates
from locations
where gates @> '[{"serial_number":"123"}]';
```

Comment: Please take a closer look at the editor and format your code and errors properly. Also, don't tag your title. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: "*datatype = _jsonb*" - that doesn't seem accurate. The error message is saying that the `gates` column has the type `jsonb[]` - the proper type would be just `jsonb`. Do not use postgres arrays of json(b) values!